# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY when using XMLRPC for android

Tags: android, xml-rpc

I have an android project that uses the xmlrpc library. I downloaded the xmlrpc library and imported into my eclipse workspace. I then added it to the build path in my android project and use it. When I go to run in the emulator, I get this error: "Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY". Are the xmlrpc classes not being packaged into my android project? Help...

Comment: Please post your manifest as you may have elements in it which mean you're asking for system libraries which aren't available where your running the app.

Answer (score 10):

This error happens if you try to install your Map application on a device (i.e.) AVD doesn't have Google API support. 
Try creating a new AVD with Google API and use that. It helped in my case.

Comment: Thx Prasanta,
created a new AVD device with Google API and solved it for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too when I added xmlrpc library for android , I solved it by copying the whole package of xmlrpc library from src folder of library to my project.